# Solving the definite integral of trig function

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I'd like to ask for some feedback on my calculation.  Please let me know if you think it's correct, or if I messed up somewhere:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi^2}{4}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,\sin{(4\pi+\sqrt{x})}}\,\,dx$$

Using substitution:

$$u = \sqrt{x},\,\,\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}},\,\,du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}dx$$

So

$$2\int{\sin{(4\pi+u)}}du = 2[-\cos{(4\pi+u)}]+c = -2\cos{(4\pi+\sqrt{x})}+c$$

Evaluating the integral bounds

$$=(-2\cos{(4\pi+\sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}{4}})}) - (-2\cos{(4\pi+\sqrt{0})})$$
$$=(-2\cos{(4\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})})-(-2\cos{(4\pi+0)})$$
$$=(-2\cdot 0) - (-2\cdot 1) = 2$$

I'd appreciate anyone's input on my work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to substitute $$u=4\pi +\sqrt x$$

Comment: Hi Fermat, thanks for the advice.  Why would you say it's better to substitute the whole expression?

Comment: Hi @ptikobj because $du={1\over 2\sqrt x}dx$ but it not so different from yours...